# Выбор формы документа программно

Tags: 1с

Имеется документ,при нажатии на создание,открывается список, от выбора в этом списке значения открывается своя форма, как получить этот выбор при программном заполнении?
Пробовал "получить форму", выходит,что после программного заполнения документа форма не сохраняется всё равно. И при открытии нового(созданного программно) документа меня просит выбрать форму что б открыть док,я выбираю нужную форму и док пустой.
Сформулирую чётче вопрос. Как при программном создании и заполнении документа выбрать нужную форму документа и сохранить её?

Comment: Обычное либо управляемое приложение?

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение, полез в модуль менеджера документа,стал искать всё связанное с формой необходимой мне по её наименованию, нашёл реквизит ссылочного типа на перечисления, который участвовал в условии (Если реквизит=значению, тогда выбор формы), ну и в итоге выбрав нужное значение реквизита была и притянута форма. Всем спасибо

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]